# Equidistant letter pattern using regex

Tags: c++, regex, regex-group

Consider the following:

We've got a grid with **X**, **O** that is represented by the single string **T**.

My task is to check whether there exists a subset **S** of **X** in the string **T**, where the distance between every character in **S** is equal (i.e.  we can observe an equidistant letter sequencing). I'll provide a few examples.

X X X — true, as the distance equals 0

X o X o X — true, as the distance equals 1

X o x X o o X — true, as the distance equals 2 and there's a subset of X with indices: [0, 3, 6]

Could this task be solved with regular expression? I've come up with this one: `".*?((X|O).{0,2})\1\2.*"`, although it fails on some tests (X o x X o x X is matched, while X o o X o x X is not).

Besides; is there a clever way to achieve this with a single regular expression? I presume we're still able to generate multiple regular expressions for every distance we need to check, such as:  `"(.*?(X|O)\1\1.*)|(.*?(X|O).\1.\1.*)|(.*?(X|O).{2}\1.{2}\1.*)"`

Comment: Can you be certain that the characters between the X's will always be the same, or (as shown in your test cases) will the letters be different, with only X's staying the same? If you can sanitize your inputs, the resulting regex is as simple as `^(X (?:[^X\s] )*)\1*X$`

Comment: Certainly **S** always exists: it might be empty, and it can obviously have just one element if there are any **X**s.  Do you mean to find the largest such set?